# Finite difference method for periodic ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

I've been learning about how to solve ODEs using the finite difference method by reducing them to systems of linear equations, like this:

$$y^{\prime}(x)=y(x)^2+4y(x)-12$$
This can be reduced to a linear system of ODEs:
$$y^{\prime}(x)=a(x)-12$$
$$a^{\prime}(x)=2y(x)-4$$
And then to a finite difference equation.
$$\frac{y(x)-y(x-h)}{h}=a(x)-12$$
$$\frac{a(x)-a(x-h)}{h}=2y(x)+4$$
Discretize the domain,
$$y_i-y_{i-1}-ha_i=-12h$$
$$a_i-a_{i-1}+2hy_i=4h$$
and put it in matrix form.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & & & & & & & & \\
-1 & 1 & & & & & -h & & & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & & & & & \ddots & & \\
& & -1 & 1 & & & & & -h & \\
& & & & 1 & & & & & \\
& & & & & 1 & & & & \\
& 2h & & & & -1 & 1 & & & \\
& & \ddots & & & & \ddots & \ddots & & \\
& & & 2h & & & & -1 & 1 & \\
& & & & & & & & & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_{n-1} \\
y_n \\
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_{n-1} \\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y(0) \\
-12h \\
\vdots \\
-12h\\
y(n)\\
a(0)\\
4h\\
\vdots\\
4h\\
a(n)
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $y(0)$, $y(n)$, $a(0)$, and $a(n)$ are known boundary conditions.

Is that correct, and can this method be used to solve infinitely differentiable ODEs, like this example?
$$y^{\prime}(x)=sin(y)$$

Comment: It's not quite correct.  You should have
$$a'(x) = 2y(x)y'(x) + 4y'(x).$$
You can't forget to multiply by $y'(x)$ when using the chain rule.

This error invalidates the rest of your post.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: In what sense is the ODE or the IVP periodic? $y'=(y+6)(y-2)$ has monotonic or constant solutions, there is nothing periodic to find.

Comment: I was asking how the example at the bottom could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your example equation is a Riccati equation. This allows to derive a system by setting $y=\frac{a}{b}$, inserting into the ODE, multiplying with the common denominator $b^2$ and then splitting the equation into two linear ones. The last step is not unique, there may be multiple sensible variants.
\begin{align}
a'b-ab'&=a^2+4ab-12b^2\\
(a'-4a+12b)b&=a(b'+a)
\end{align}
Having a functional degree of dependence free to assign, one can chose to set both sides to zero separately, resulting in the linear system
\begin{align}
a'&=4a-12b\\
b'&=-a
\end{align}
You can now discretize this like you did with your attempt. I would recommend to use the trapezoidal method for a higher error order with not really more effort.

Or you can insert the second equation into the first to get the second order linear DE
$$
b''-4b'-12b=0
$$
and use central difference quotients on this one to get a tridiagonal system matrix.